# I am trying to make a registration form with mysql in java and it gives me an error

Tags: java, mysql

Error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '='Name'' at line 1

My code:

```
public void register(){
    try {
    String name="Name";
        PreparedStatement updateSales = conn.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)");
        updateSales.setString(1, name); 
        updateSales.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: where is line 1?

Comment: Set a breakpoint before the executeUpdate statement, use the debugger to copy the contents of the action query into the clipboard, then paste it into your mySQL client and see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Your error message mentions `='Name'`, yet this text appears nowhere in the SQL string you are running.  Are you absolutely sure that the exception you are getting is being thrown from the method above?  My first instinct is that is actually being thrown from somewhere else in your code.